# Setting Google Map Markers in Vue3 / Pinia

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, vuejs3, pinia

I'd like to show markers based on data fetched from a vue3 pinia store. I'm having difficulty setting my first marker on the map:

```js
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader'
import { useDiscoverItemStore } from "@/stores/DiscoverItemStore"
const discoverStore = useDiscoverItemStore()

const MAPS_API_KEY = 'api-key'

const loader = new Loader({ apiKey: MAPS_API_KEY })
const mapDiv = ref(null)
let map = ref(null)

onMounted(async () => {
  await loader.load()
  map.value = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv.value, {
    center: currPos.value,
    zoom: 13,
  })

  await discoverStore.fetchItems()
  let loc = new google.maps.LatLng(discoverStore.items[0].location[0], discoverStore.items[0].location[1])

  console.log(loc)
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: loc,
    map, // have also tried `map: map` 
    title: "Hello World!",
  })

  // have also tried `marker.setMap(map)`
})
</script>
```

My console is telling me that `setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama`. Here's the full readout from my console:

[image: Console Readout]

Why can't I add this marker to my google maps `map` `ref`? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *have also tried `map: map`* have you tried `map: map.value` since you did `map.value = new google.maps.Map` it makes sense to do so - but why does `map` need to be a ref?

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX, this did indeed work. Please feel free to suggest it as the answer to the question. For why `map` needs to be a `ref` tbh I'm a newbie to vue so I'm unsure. Without it, though, it doesn't work. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4ad3eEFhAo) which may give you more insight.

Comment: I guess `map` is also used elsewhere that you haven't shown?

Comment: `map` ref is reactive. Unless you make use of its reactivity, it doesn't benefit from being a ref, it could be a variable that is local to onMounted

Answer (score 0):

Your Google map instance is on `map.value`

```
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: loc,
    map: map.value,
    title: "Hello World!",
  })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).